# Move method getData() in another class with java?

Tags: java, android

How can move the methods like getData() in another class and after call that class in this page? 
I try to do something, but it doesn't work.
Can you help to create a new class?

`package it.example.app.fragment_2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Tab1 extends Fragment  implements RecyclerView.OnScrollChangeListener {

  View v;
    private Tab1.OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private List<SuperHero> listSuperHeroes;

    //Creating Views
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    //Volley Request Queue
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;

    //The request counter to send ?page=1, ?page=2  requests
    private int requestCount = 1;

    public Tab1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        listSuperHeroes = new ArrayList<>();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        getData();
        adapter = new CardAdapter(listSuperHeroes, getContext());
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return v;
    }

    //This integer will used to specify the page number for the request ?page = requestcount
    //This method would return a JsonArrayRequest that will be added to the request queue
    private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
        //Initializing ProgressBar
        //final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        //Displaying Progressbar
        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        //JsonArrayRequest of volley
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                        parseData(response);
                        //Hiding the progressbar
                        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                       // progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                       // Toast.makeText(Hero_main_activity.this, "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        //Returning the request
        return jsonArrayRequest;
    }

    //This method will get data from the web api
    private void getData() {
        //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer
        requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
        //Incrementing the request counter
        requestCount++;
    }

    //This method will parse json data
    private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            //Creating the superhero object
            SuperHero superHero = new SuperHero();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                //Getting json
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                //Adding data to the superhero object
                superHero.setImageUrl(json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
                superHero.setName(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));
                superHero.setPublisher(json.getString(Config.TAG_PUBLISHER));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Adding the superhero object to the list
            listSuperHeroes.add(superHero);
        }

        //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //This method would check that the recyclerview scroll has reached the bottom or not
    private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Overriden method to detect scrolling
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
        //Ifscrolled at last then
        if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
            //Calling the method getdata again
            getData();
        }
    }
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}`

Comment: According to the Fragment lifecycle, you should call your logic like getData() in the onViewCreated() , since onCreateView is just for inflating and finding views for that Fragment

Comment: i don't understand. Can you explain me ?

Comment: [This](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/create-java-class)? Also, you say you tried something but it doesn't work. That does not help us help you, so please share what you have tried and how it does not work. In addition, what Gastón said above is unrelated to your question but merely a comment on your unideal place to actually get the data to show in your view. It seems you should only get data after the view was created, not before.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to call getData() function in other class/activity/fragment.

It's not the best way but, you can create another class which has a static variable (public static Tab1 tab1;) and in the Tab1.onCreateView(...) you can set this variable (OtherClass.tab1 = this;). (Also you have to make public getData function).

But there is a problem which if a class/activity/fragment try to reach getData function before the Tab1, it will give NullPointEx...

I don't know what you really want but, I think you have to change the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

> **This might not be the best way out but you can sure count on it...**
>
> SIMPLY CREATE AN INSTANCE OF THE TAB1 FRAGMENT CLASS THIS SHOULD HELP
>   INSTANTIATE THE CLASS IF IT HAS NOT BE INSTANTIATED BEFORE

```
private static Tab1 single_instance = null;
        public static Tab1 getInstance(){
            if (single_instance == null)
                single_instance = new Tab1();
            return single_instance;
        }
```

> I WILL ASSUME THIS IS ANY OTHER CLASS THAT WANTS TO CALL getData()
>   FROM TAB1 IT IS DONE BY SIMPLY USING TAB1 INSTANCE VARIABLE LIKE WE
>   DECLEARED JUST BELOW.

```
public class ClassCaller{
    Tab1 tab1 = Tab1.getInstance();
```

> THIS CAN BE ANY METHOD IN THE CALLER CLASS, IT CAN BE onCreate() OR
>   ANY OTHER.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
       if(something_is_true)
         tab1.getData();
    }

}
```

***kindly put in mind I did not test this code, just want you to give it a try.***